# Reemplazar texto dinámico en un bloque de texto - PLSQL - REGEX

Tags: sql, oracle, regex, plsql

Como puedo reemplazar un texto en plsql que no se sabe la posición actual ni la longitud de la frase, tampoco se sabe la posición porque puede ser dinámica.

las posibles soluciones a las que he podido llegar es la siguiente, lo he probado en plataformas online de regex y me da el resultado esperado, pero al implementarlo obtengo valores inesperados.

el patrón que he encontrado es que la mayoría de las veces o termina en `,` o `;` o un `espacio` y casi siempre la palabra `USO:`, por ejemplo: `FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX;` USO:

palabras a extraer o sustituir:

- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX;
- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y
  EMPAQUE: BOTELLA ALUMINIO POR: 5KG, 10 KG, 20 KG, 25KG, 50KG, 100 gr,
  250 gr, 500 gr, 300gr - CAJAS POR: 10 KG , 15 KG, 20 KG, 25 KG,
  50LB, - TAMBOR POR: 25 KG, 50 KG, 5KG, 50 LB, 180 KG, 20KG, 4KG -
  GARRAFA POR: 10 KG , 25 KG, 20 KG, 5KG, 10 KG, 1 KG, - SACOS POR: 20
  KG, 25KG, 50LB, 10KG - FRASCOS POR: 25gr, 250gr, 500gr, 100gr, 250gr,
  1 KG, 300gr, 1000gr - TARROS POR: 1000gr, 20 gr, 25gr, 100 gr,
  2500gr, 250gr, 500gr, 50gr, 1KG. ;
- FORMA DE PRESENTACION Y EMPAQUE/
  PRESENTACION COMERCIAL: CAJAS DE 15KG // 20KG // 25KG // SACOS DE
  22.68KG // FRASCOS DE 0.05KG // 0.025KG // 0.10KG // 0.25KG // 0.50KG // 0.30 KG // 1KG;
- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX PENDT XXXX;
- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: *** PENDIENTE
  ***;

Texto:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit tortor non erat rhoncus, ac fermentum eros blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ullamcorper tellus non nulla suscipit, et eleifend eros sagittis. Aenean iaculis eu mauris at egestas. Nullam ac interdum libero. En `ENVASE Y FORMATO DE ENVASE: XXX;` USO: volutpat venenatis ullamcorper. In tempus lorem vel turpis lacinia ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut eleifend nulla magna, ut malesuada quam dapibus vitae. Mauris et molestie libero.

Regex:

`^.*?(FORMA\sDE\sPRESENTACI[OÓ]?N\sY\sEMPAQUE(?:(?:[\/\s]+)PRESENTACI[OÓ]N\sCOMERCIAL)?(?:[\:\s[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ,0-9;\.%*\t\-]+)[,;]\s)(?:[U]).*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tCbwNR/1)

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que quieres lograr o sustituir al final de cuentas.